# ASDF is searching for a library in too many directories

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

When my app tries to connect to an sqlite DB with `mito:connect-toplevel`, it takes ages and indeed, ASDF is scanning directories recursively and scans several `node_modules` !

But *this only happens with an executable, not on Slime*.

It may be my environment's fault, but I don't have anything fancy in my .sbclrc (anymore).

And the thing is, I already observed this behaviour with `asdf:system-relative-pathname`, which I avoided in another app, but now this happens with a third party library.

My models.connect:

```
(defun connect ()
  (format t "connecting to ~a...~&" *db-name*)
  (force-output)
  (setf *db* (connect-toplevel :sqlite3 :database-name *db-name*))
  (format t "...done~&")
  (force-output))
```

Then I build an executable, I run it from the command line in the `~/projects/bookshops` directory (not `~/bacasable` which we see below) and kill it when it's busy:

```
connecting to db.db...
^CUnhandled SB-SYS:INTERACTIVE-INTERRUPT in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD
                                                "main thread" RUNNING
                                                    {1008E269A3}>:
Interactive interrupt at #x10002A6808.

Backtrace for: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1008E269A3}>
0: (SB-KERNEL:HAIRY-DATA-VECTOR-SET #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable argument>) [tl,external]
1: (CONCATENATE SIMPLE-STRING "/" "home" "/" "vince" "/" "bacasable" "/" "testabelujo" "/" "abelujo" "/" "node_modules" "/" "testcafe-browser-tools" "/" "bin" "/" "linux" "/")
2: (SB-IMPL::UNPARSE-UNIX-NAMESTRING #P"/home/vince/bacasable/testabelujo/abelujo/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/bin/linux/")
3: (NAMESTRING #P"/home/vince/bacasable/testabelujo/abelujo/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/bin/linux/")
4: ((FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::PATHNAME-KEY :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) #P"/home/vince/bacasable/testabelujo/abelujo/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/bin/linux/")
5: ((FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::RECURSEP :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) #P"/home/vince/bacasable/testabelujo/abelujo/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/bin/linux/")
6: (UIOP/FILESYSTEM:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES #P"/home/vince/bacasable/testabelujo/abelujo/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/bin/" #<CLOSURE (FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::COLLECTP :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) {100923C1CB}> #<CLOSURE (FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::RECURSEP :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) {100923C1FB}> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST SB-IMPL::ARGUMENTS) :IN CONSTANTLY) {100923C21B}>)
7: (UIOP/FILESYSTEM:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES #P"/home/vince/bacasable/testabelujo/abelujo/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/" #<CLOSURE (FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::COLLECTP :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) {100923C1CB}> #<CLOSURE (FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::RECURSEP :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) {100923C1FB}> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST SB-IMPL::ARGUMENTS) :IN CONSTANTLY) {100923C21B}>)
8: (UIOP/FILESYSTEM:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES #P"/home/vince/bacasable/testabelujo/abelujo/node_modules/" #<CLOSURE (FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::COLLECTP :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) {100923C1CB}> #<CLOSURE (FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::RECURSEP :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) {100923C1FB}> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST SB-IMPL::ARGUMENTS) :IN CONSTANTLY) {100923C21B}>)
9: (UIOP/FILESYSTEM:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES #P"/home/vince/bacasable/testabelujo/abelujo/" #<CLOSURE (FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::COLLECTP :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) {100923C1CB}> #<CLOSURE (FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::RECURSEP :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) {100923C1FB}> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST SB-IMPL::ARGUMENTS) :IN CONSTANTLY) {100923C21B}>)
10: (UIOP/FILESYSTEM:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES #P"/home/vince/bacasable/testabelujo/" #<CLOSURE (FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::COLLECTP :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) {100923C1CB}> #<CLOSURE (FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::RECURSEP :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) {100923C1FB}> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST SB-IMPL::ARGUMENTS) :IN CONSTANTLY) {100923C21B}>)
11: (UIOP/FILESYSTEM:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES #P"/home/vince/bacasable/" #<CLOSURE (FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::COLLECTP :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) {100923C1CB}> #<CLOSURE (FLET ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY::RECURSEP :IN ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COLLECT-SUB*DIRECTORIES-ASD-FILES) {100923C1FB}> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST SB-IMPL::ARGUMENTS) :IN CONSTANTLY) {100923C21B}>)
12: (ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:COMPUTE-SOURCE-REGISTRY NIL #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 17 {10091B5463}>)
13: (ASDF/SOURCE-REGISTRY:ENSURE-SOURCE-REGISTRY NIL)
14: (ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY:SYSDEF-SOURCE-REGISTRY-SEARCH "dbd-sqlite3")
15: ((FLET ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY::TRY :IN ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY:SEARCH-FOR-SYSTEM-DEFINITION) ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY:SYSDEF-SOURCE-REGISTRY-SEARCH)
16: ((FLET ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY::TRY :IN ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY:SEARCH-FOR-SYSTEM-DEFINITION) ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY:SYSDEF-SOURCE-REGISTRY-SEARCH) [external]
17: (SB-KERNEL:%MAP-FOR-EFFECT-ARITY-1 #<CLOSURE (FLET ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY::TRY :IN ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY:SEARCH-FOR-SYSTEM-DEFINITION) {10091B480B}> (ASDF/PACKAGE-INFERRED-SYSTEM:SYSDEF-PACKAGE-INFERRED-SYSTEM-SEARCH ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY:SYSDEF-CENTRAL-REGISTRY-SEARCH ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY:SYSDEF-SOURCE-REGISTRY-SEARCH QUICKLISP-CLIENT:LOCAL-PROJECTS-SEARCHER QL-DIST:SYSTEM-DEFINITION-SEARCHER))
18: (ASDF/SYSTEM-REGISTRY:SEARCH-FOR-SYSTEM-DEFINITION "dbd-sqlite3")
19: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/FIND-SYSTEM:LOCATE-SYSTEM))
20: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/SYSTEM:FIND-SYSTEM))
21: (ASDF/SESSION:CONSULT-ASDF-CACHE (ASDF/SYSTEM:FIND-SYSTEM "dbd-sqlite3") #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/SYSTEM:FIND-SYSTEM) {10091B387B}>)
22: (ASDF/SESSION:CALL-WITH-ASDF-SESSION #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/SYSTEM:FIND-SYSTEM) {10091B387B}> :OVERRIDE NIL :KEY (ASDF/SYSTEM:FIND-SYSTEM "dbd-sqlite3") :OVERRIDE-CACHE NIL :OVERRIDE-FORCING NIL)
23: ((LABELS QUICKLISP-CLIENT::RECURSE :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT::COMPUTE-LOAD-STRATEGY) "dbd-sqlite3")
24: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT::COMPUTE-LOAD-STRATEGY)) [external]
25: (QL-DIST::CALL-WITH-CONSISTENT-DISTS #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT::COMPUTE-LOAD-STRATEGY) {10091B37DB}>)
26: (QUICKLISP-CLIENT::COMPUTE-LOAD-STRATEGY #<unavailable argument>)
27: (QUICKLISP-CLIENT::AUTOLOAD-SYSTEM-AND-DEPENDENCIES "dbd-sqlite3" :PROMPT NIL)
28: ((:METHOD QL-IMPL-UTIL::%CALL-WITH-QUIET-COMPILATION (T T)) #<unavailable argument> #<CLOSURE (FLET QUICKLISP-CLIENT::QL :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD) {10091B301B}>) [fast-method]
29: ((:METHOD QL-IMPL-UTIL::%CALL-WITH-QUIET-COMPILATION :AROUND (QL-IMPL:SBCL T)) #<QL-IMPL:SBCL {10011057E3}> #<CLOSURE (FLET QUICKLISP-CLIENT::QL :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD) {10091B301B}>) [fast-method]
30: ((:METHOD QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD (T)) #<unavailable argument> :PROMPT NIL :SILENT T :VERBOSE NIL) [fast-method]
31: (QL-DIST::CALL-WITH-CONSISTENT-DISTS #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD) {100919ECDB}>)
32: (DBI::LOAD-DRIVER :SQLITE3)
33: (DBI:CONNECT :SQLITE3 :DATABASE-NAME "db.db")
34: (MITO.CONNECTION:CONNECT-TOPLEVEL :SQLITE3 :DATABASE-NAME "db.db")
35: (BOOKSHOPS.MODELS:CONNECT)
36: (BOOKSHOPS::INIT)
37: (BOOKSHOPS:MAIN)
38: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN UIOP/IMAGE:RESTORE-IMAGE))
39: (UIOP/IMAGE:CALL-WITH-FATAL-CONDITION-HANDLER #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN UIOP/IMAGE:RESTORE-IMAGE) {1008E3CD2B}>)
40: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-89 :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))
41: ((LABELS SB-IMPL::RESTART-LISP :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))
```

What could cause this in my environment ?

Is it normal ASDF does this, why only with the executable ?

ASDF "3.3.1.2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASDF is building its source registry from several possible places in the filesystem:

- `~/common-lisp/`
- `~/.local/share/common-lisp/source/`
- the definitions in `~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf` and `~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf.d/`
- and more…

See:

- https://www.common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Configuring-ASDF
- https://www.common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Controlling-where-ASDF-searches-for-systems

Quicklisp adds its `local-projects` directory, I think.

You'd need to look through those lists to find out what is happening.  I guess that you somewhere put a symbolic link to that `~/bacasable/` directory into a directory that is searched by ASDF.

By the way, I find the programmatic downloading of a needed driver by a library at runtime a bit questionable.  There should be some way around that.

Maybe you could try to force loading of the driver before saving your executable.

Comment: I had checked a couple places but I hadn't checked the doc and all of them. And in `~/.config/…/source-registry.conf.d/` I have a file with `(:tree (:home "bacasable/"))`… it dates back of at least one year. Thank you ! <3

Comment: "force loading of the driver" any more doc about that ?

Comment: I just meant loading it into the image (take a look at that `dbi::load-driver`), before you call `save-lisp-and-die` (or whatever you use).

Comment: By the way, having link cycles in a directory searched by ASDF is also a quick way to make your installation unusable.  I nowadays only use `~/common-lisp`, and only for lisp repos.